# How to extract specific cells of an HTML table

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

There is a table that I want to pull info from, and for every row there are three cells across, but I only want the second cell from each of the rows. I am using Simple HTML DOM to retrieve the info, but how could I write, perhaps a loop?, the code to only get the second of the cells?

This is what I have now. Where do I go from here?

```
$html = file_get_html("http://url.com");
foreach($html->find("table[class=list-table]") as $top5)
{
echo($top5->plaintext);
}
```

Comment: Loop through every row and select the second cell inside that loop. What have you already tried?

Comment: Yes, but how can I select only that second cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm), I would extract the rows `tr` and then pick the second cell `td` from each row

```
$html = file_get_html("http://url.com");
foreach($html->find("table[class=list-table] tr") as $tr)
{
    $td = $tr->find('td', 1);
}
```

Instead of `table[class=list-table]`, you can also use `table.list-table` for a `class` attribute, of course.

Comment: you rock man! the selectors look a little different from css. where can i find a detail of selectors usable in this library?

Comment: The selectors are the same as in CSS, see [W3C - Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). The brackets select an attribute `class` with value `list-table`. You can also look at the link in the answer below "How to find HTML elements?". When you select the various tabs, you see the different selectors available.

Answer (score 0):

You can get every second cell with:

```
table[class=list-table] td[2]
```

or more simply:

```
table.list-table td[2]
```